# Get compiled HTML sourcecode via C#

Tags: c#, html, chromium

How do you do?

How can I get the compiled source code of a website? C# gives me with the normal methods only the source code that is generated before. I need the one that will be displayed in Chrome when I look at the page in Chrome.

Ill tryed it with Webclient, StreamReader and so on.

In this case i wan't that:
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DQn8.png)

Mercy

Comment: In Java, you can use HtmlUnit. It was also ported to C# (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/NHtmlUnit), but this project is not actively developed anymore, as it seems.

Comment: What do you mean by "source code that is generated before". HTML is not a compiled language. You could use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the HTML

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev I think he wants the javascript code in the HTML document to be executed. For that he needs to load the website with a headless browser like HtmlUnit.